# jQuery - display : none not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I created a webpage in which :

- When the user clicks a button a iframe opens
- I did it by making the iframe `display:none` in the css file
- When the button is clicked, the `display` property becomes `inline` (by jQuery)

But, as the iframe is shown, there's a `close` button also. Which is when clicked, the iframe `display` becomes `none` again. But, the problem is it's not working. In short, the `display:none` from the close button not working.

My codes are as following :

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$("#a_addupdate").click(function(){
    $("#iframe_add_update").css(
        "display" , "inline"    
    );
 });
}); //This will show the iframe


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#close_frame").click(function(){
        $("#iframe_add_update").css(
        "display" , "none"
        );

    });
} //This will hide the frame
```

Edit: I'm also using `z-index:2` for iframe

Comment: You can use `hide()` and `show()` functions

Comment: I guess `$("#close_frame").click()` not working! not .`css()`

Comment: first check your both functions with dummy alert() are the working fine or not?

Comment: `z-index:2` for which element.

Comment: Tried that, but the amazing part is the `show()` is working, but not the `hide()` one.

Comment: can you also add a html snippet?

Comment: Where is the "close" button? On the `iframe` by any chance?

Comment: yes, the close button is in the iframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the close button is on the iframe, you should use:

```
// code in your iframe
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#close_frame").click(function(){
        $("#iframe_add_update", window.parent.document).css(
        "display" , "none"
        );

    });
}
```

Note the `window.parent.document` bit. This will make your code search for the `#iframe_add_update` element on the parent page.

This will work assuming you have `jQuery` in your `iframe` also and they are both in the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can update to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#iframe_add_update").contents().find("#close_frame").click(function() {
    $("#iframe_add_update").css("display", "none");
  });
}); //This will hide the frame
```

`$("#iframe_add_update").contents()` lets you find the content inside the iframes.